# Как дописать файл на FTP через python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
log_start = io.BytesIO(b'ABC\n')
ftp.storbinary('STOR log.txt', log_start, rb)
log_end = io.BytesIO(b'DEF\n')
ftp.storbinary('STOR log.txt', log_end, rb)
```

При выполнении этого кода файл log.txt перезаписывается, мне нужно что-бы log_end дозаписывал файл а не перезаписывал

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, в каком режиме вы открываете файл для записи. Вы открываете в режиме rb, то есть чтение в байтовом формате. Попробуйте открыть в режиме ab - она не перезаписывает, а добавляет в байтовом формате.

Comment: Это же обращение к `ftp server`, а не просто файл в файловой системе :)

Comment: @CrazyElf вы правы, ошибся :-)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно разобрался в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html), можно использовать параметр `rest` (соответствующий команде `ftp` `REST`), но сначала нужно получить размер файла через `size`:

```
filesize = ftp.size('STOR log.txt')
ftp.storbinary('STOR log.txt', log_end, rb, rest=filesize)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ дописываем в конец файла
```

Но всё это нужно проверять на конкретном `ftp` сервере, они не сильно стандартизованы, какие-то команды могут и не поддерживаться вашим конкретным сервером.

Какие-то сервера могут поддерживать и команду `APPEND`, но я что-то не нашёл интерфейса к ней в стандартной питоновской библиотеке с `ftp` клиентом.

Comment: Не понимаю что не так

ftplib.error_perm: 550 SIZE not allowed in ASCII mode


Меняю на байтовый режим файл не находит

ftplib.error_perm: 550 STOR log.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Хм, странно. Но вообще вы размер на своей стороне можете считать, наверное - вы же весь файл сами пишете, можете `filesize = len(b'ABC\n')` сами посчитать. Хотя через `SIZE` было бы, конечно, универсальнее.